# Tensorflow - using estimator in interactive mode

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I am trying to use a tensorflow neural network in "interactive" mode:
my goal would be to load a trained model, keeping it in memory, and then perform inference on it once in a while.

The problem is that apparently the tensorflow Estimator class (tf.estimator.Estimator) does not allow to do so.

The method predict ([documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator#predict), [source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.8/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py#L435)) takes as input a batch of features and the path to the model. Then it creates a session, loads the model and perform the inference.
After that, the session is closed and for a successive inference it is necessary to load the model again.

How could I achieve my desired behavior using the Estimator class?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at [`tfe.make_template`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/eager/make_template), its goal is precisely to make graph-based code available in eager mode.

Following [the example given during the 2018 TF summit](https://youtu.be/T8AW0fKP0Hs?t=778), that would give something like

```
def apply_my_estimator(x)
  return my_estimator(x)

t = tfe.make_template('f', apply_my_estimator, create_graph_function=True)
print(t(x))
```